# Error with SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, moodle

I am porting a Moodle 1.0 module to version 2.0. While checking for errors in several PHP files, I ran into an error message for a query, but there was no indication of what the error was. Here is the query:

```
global $DB; //required global variable

$vms = $DB->get_records_sql('SELECT DISTINCT vm.*, uva.assignment_id, gm.groupid,
                                    CASE WHEN gm.groupid IS NULL THEN uva.user_id ELSE NULL END user_id
                                    FROM {mdl_vMoodle_Virtual_Machine} vm 
                                    INNER JOIN {mdl_vMoodle_UVA} uva ON vm.id = uva.vm_id 
                                    LEFT JOIN {mdl_groups_members} gm ON gm.userid = uva.user_id
                                    WHERE uva.assignment_id = :assignmentid', array('assignmentid'=>$assignment_id));
```

can anyone tell me what is incorrect about this function call?

Update: Removing DISTINCT made the error go away. Moodle 2.0 has very little documentation, so I'm not sure if it simply does not accept the distinct keyword.

Comment: Don't see any syntax problems with this query.  I'm not familiar with how Moodle binds PDO parameters, but typically a PDO param array will include the `:` in its keys as in `array(':assignmentid' => $assignment_id)` (though I think it is optional)

Comment: "I ran into an error message for a query"  So tell us what the error message said.  Paste it exactly, not a paraphrase.

Comment: ERROR ( OTHER ) - line 327 - This is the exact error. It does not say anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Don't add the table names prefix "mdl_", because by using {} it's added automatically.

Comment: In this case, the mdl_ is actually the way I named the tables in the database; it isn't a Moodle thing.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL syntax is OK, so that isn't the problem. You need to check the value of $assignment_id, the variable is probably not set, or set with an improper type of value, and that is what is causing the error.

I suggest you to add:

```
var_dump($assignment_id);
```

right before this query and see what you get. If you get an "undefined" message then check on the logic of your software to see what might be causing this.

Comment: Well, this is before actually running the script, so it has to be a syntax error. Perhaps something specific to Moodle?

Comment: Hmm.....Are you sure this is the whole code? From the structure that you are pasting, it seems like you are using PDO or some other library to pass the variables to the query. Please edit your post and add what is right BEFORE this piece of code. If there is nothing else then you are missing something, because your code seems like the arguments of a function call.